# Changing #include filenames to match case

Tags: c++, c, sed

I have a body of C/C++ source code where the filename in the #include statement does not match the *.h file exactly. The match is correct, but is case insensitive. This is the type of source files that occur in a Windows system.

I want to change all the source files so that all `#include` statements are exact matches to the filenames they refer to.

All filenames to change are enclosed in quotes.

Example:

List of files

```
File1.h
FILE2.H
file1.cpp
```

file1.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
```

Change file1.cpp to

```
#include "File1.h"
#include "FILE2.H"
```

I would like to create an automated script to perform this update.

I have listed steps below that are pieces of this process, but I can't seem to bring the pieces together.

1. Create a list of all *.h files, `ls *.h > include.lst`. This creates a file of all the filenames with the correct case.
2. Using the filenames in `include.lst` create a sed command `'s/<filename>/<filename>/I'` which does a case insensitive search and replaces the match with properly cased filename. I believe I only have to do the replacement once, but adding the global g will take care of multiple occurances.
3. Apply this list of replacements to all files in a directory.

I would like suggestions on how to create the sed command 2) given `include.lst`. I think I can handle the rest.

Comment: Or consider fixing your source tree to conform to C lang conventions. Use script to generate `mv FILE2.H file2.h`. JMHO. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, lowercasing all the files is the final goal, but one step at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `sed` in script, or use Perl script:

   ```
   find . -name *.c -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak -e "s/\#include\s\"\([^\"]+/)\"/\#include\s\"\L\1\"/"
   ```

   `-i.bak` will back up the file to `original_file_name.bak` so you do not need to worry if you mess up

   This line changes all header includes to lower case in your C files.
2. Then you want to change all files names:

   ```
   find . -name *.h -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/(*)/\L\1/'
   ```

   This renames all header file to lower case.

This is for linux only. If you are using Windows, you might want to use Perl or Python script for all above.

Comment: I like the idea of changing all the files to lowercase, but with the source under version control, many files names are changed, resulting in some files being deleted and other being new, as seen from version control perspective. Need to have version control be aware of the file renames.

Comment: @KeithSmith: That can be done using the same method as the `rename`. E.g in Perforce it'd be `p4 edit` followed by `p4 move`

Comment: @MSalters - Yes. SVN has svn move. Git has git mv. Mercurial has hg rename. The concern I have, since I don't rename files often, is the loss of history when the file is renamed.

Comment: @KeithSmith: Any decent repository keeps the file history over a rename.

Comment: I ended up using the follow command. `find . -name *.c -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak -e "s/#include\s\"([^\"]+/)\"/#include\s\"\L\1\"/"` for my variant of bash and sed.

Answer (score 2):

```
for hfile in $(find /header/dir -type f -iname '*.h'); do
    sed -i 's/#include "'$hfile'"/#include "'$hfile'"/gI' file1.cpp
done
```

I hope I got the quotes right :) Try without `-i` before applying.

You can wrap the `sed` call in another loop like this:

```
for hfile in $(find /header/dir -type f -iname '*.h'); do
    for sfile in $(find /source/dir -type f -iname '*.cpp'); do
        sed -i 's/#include "'$hfile'"/#include "'$hfile'"/gI' "$sfile"
    done
done
```

Comment: Use double quotes outside for interpolation.

Comment: @texasbruce I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by interpolation here. I could use double quotes everywhere in the `sed` command, but I'd have to escape the double quotes in the substitution then.

Comment: @texasbruce Ah, right, but the quotes are not mandatory, are they? `test='FOO'; echo $test'BAR'` works fine...

Comment: No variable interpolation does not occur if you do `'$variable'`. And also in a single quoted string, you should escape single quotes too.

Comment: @texasbruce Right, but in my answer, the interpolation happens _outside_ the single quotes. I break them exactly to insert the variables and the start again. Consider: `test='BAR'; echo 'foo'$test'baz'`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|s/^#include "&"$/#include "&"/i|' list_of_files | sed -i -f - *.{cpp,h}
```

Comment: Not a complete solution as one has to change #include files in *.h files as well as *.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the details on lowercasing filenames and #include strings.
However, my original question was to perform a literal replacement.

Below is the basic command and sed script that met my requirements.

`ls *.h *.H | sed -e "s/\([^\r\n]*\)/s\/\\\(\\\#include\\\s\\\"\\\)\1\\\"\/\\\1\1\\\"\/gi/g" >> sedcmd.txt`

1. `ls *.h *.H` creates a list of files, one line at a time
2. Pipe this list to sed.
3. Search for the whole line, which is a filename. Put the whole line in group 1. `s/\(^\r\n]*\)/`
4. Replace the whole line, the filename, with the string `s/\(\#include\s"\)<filename>"/\1<filename>"/gi`

The string `#include<space>"` is placed in group 1. The `i` in the `gi` states to do a case insensitive search. The `g` is the normal global search and replace.

Given a filename ACCESS.H and cancel.h, the output of the script is

```
s/\(\#include\s"\)ACCESS.H"/\1ACCESS.H"/gi
s/\(\#include\s"\)cancel.h"/\1cancel.h"/gi
```

Finally, the sed command file can be used with the command

```
sed -i.bak -f sedcmd.txt *.cpp *.h
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution doesn't fail for pathnames containing slashes (hopefully you don't contain `%` signs in your header paths).

It's also orders of magnitude faster (takes ~13 seconds on a few hundred files, as opposed to several minutes of waiting).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar failglob nocaseglob

# You should pushd to your include path-root.
pushd include/path/root
headers=( **/*.h )
popd
headers+=( *.h )    # My codebase has some extra header files in the project root.

echo ${#headers[*]} headers

# Separate each replacement with ;
regex=""
for header in "${headers[@]}"; do
   regex+=';s%#include "'"$header"'"%#include "'"$header"'"%gI'
done
regex="${regex:1}"

find . -type f -iname '*.cpp' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 sed -i "$regex"
```

It's much faster to make sed run just once per file (with many ;-separated regexes).